# How to select data in mysql that all the joined table is not null on certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 table which is one to many

**table order**

| order_id | order_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021/01/01 |
| 2 | 2021/01/02 |
| 3 | 2021/01/02 |

**table detail order**

| detail_order_id | order_id | is_finished |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 2021/01/03 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021/01/04 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021/01/04 |
| 5 | 3 | 2021/01/05 |
| 6 | 3 | 2021/01/06 |
| 7 | 3 | null |

so i wanna data that have condition if some of the detail order rows `is_finished` column not null, so the `status` is gonna be not finish.
and if all the detail order rows `is_finished` column not contain any null value like id 2, so the `status` is finished

**expected result**

| order_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | not finish |
| 2 | finished |
| 3 | not finish |

Comment: thank you everyone for answering my question, apparently there is alot of different approach to this. all the answer is working good. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't really need a join since `table_detail_order` already have `order_id` and you only want to check `is_finished`, you might just need a query on 1 table like:

```
SELECT order_id,
       CASE WHEN SUM(is_finished IS NULL)=0
            THEN 'Finished' ELSE 'Not finish' END AS 'Status'
FROM table_detail_order GROUP BY order_id;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdf6ebcf2b0942d2847d0ecbde8ce823)

Btw, `is_finished IS NULL` will return 1 (true) or 0 (false) so in a table it would look like:

| order_id | is_finished | is_finished IS NULL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 |
| 1 | 2021/01/03 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021/01/04 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021/01/04 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021/01/05 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021/01/06 | 0 |
| 3 | null | 1 |

Therefore `SUM(is_finished IS NULL)` with `GROUP BY order_id;` will do something like this:

| order_id | SUM(is_finished IS NULL) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1+0=1 |
| 2 | 0+0=0 |
| 3 | 0+0+1=1 |

And that is why `CASE WHEN SUM(is_finished IS NULL)=0 ...` is considered as `finished` while otherwise as `not finish`.

Comment: oh you can use sum on that, thats new to me. cause i think sum is just used on numbers only thank you sir

Comment: Actually the `SUM()` works because of the Boolean value returned 1 (true) or 0 (false). So, basically it return numerical value instead of date or `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

we can solve the problem like this

- left join order and order_detail,but has condition order_details.is_finished is null
- so we get a result that the joined order_details's is_finished only null
- in that case there is no order_details join with order 2
- then we regard the result as a temp table,so when joined order_details has data then it is not finished

[here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3DMXmhhM2ykNJegDMXHbAj/0) is the example data,you can run query in it

```sql
select id,
    case when order_id>0 then 'not finish' else 'finished' end as status 
from (
      select o.id,od.order_id from `order` as o 
          left join order_detail as od 
            on (o.id=od.order_id and od.is_finished is null) 
      group by o.id
) as _t
```

Comment: thank you. so temporary table and left join right. ill dig more into it.
so in that temporary table it has no od.order_id in order_ID '2'
and then you check it if there is no order_id then is finished right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This query uses a `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT`. Where the first count counted the `NULL` values as `ZERO` and the second count counts all values, then compare the 2 counts, if the first and second count is equal to each other it means that the order details is finished, if not then not finish.

```
SELECT a.`order_id`,
IF(COUNT(IF(ISNULL(is_finished),0,1))=COUNT(is_finished), 'finished', 'not finish') AS `status` FROM `order` a
LEFT JOIN `detail_order` b ON a.`order_id`=b.`order_id`
GROUP BY a.`order_id` ;
```

**RESULT***

```
order_id  status      
--------  ------------
       1  not finish  
       2  finished    
       3  not finish
```

Comment: thank you. so left join and count, ill dig more into it.
so it matches isnull(is_finished) and all of is_finished right?